# mkfifo() not able to create file in C

Tags: c, pipe, named-pipes, mkfifo

I'm trying to create a named pipe in C, but have not had any success.

Here is my code:

```
#define FIFO_NAME "/tmp/myfifo"
int main(){
    int fd;
    fd = mkfifo(FIFO_NAME, 0666);//, 0);
    if(fd<0){
      fprintf(stderr,"Error creating fifo\n");
      exit(0);
    }
```

On running the above code every time output comes out:

```
Error creating fifo
```

Please help.

Comment: use `perror` to print the actual error message

Comment: check that you have write permission on the cwd

Comment: Did you check errno? Probably EEXISTS if I had to guess.

Comment: check that there is no file already

Comment: You want to replace `fprintf(stderr,"Error creating fifo\n");` by `perror("mkfifo() failed");`. This gives you the long text error message which corresponds to the value of `errno` set by `mkfifo()` on failure.

Comment: Thanks that worked, it had a existing file by same name.

Answer (score 0):

You want to replace `fprintf(stderr,"Error creating fifo\n");` by `perror("mkfifo() failed");`. This gives you the long text error message which corresponds to the value of `errno` set by `mkfifo()` on failure.
                    – alk

Thanks that worked, it had a existing file by same name.
                    – vidit jain

Answer (score 0):

Execute the program in a Unix environment. Even the folder directory should be in the Unix environment. Also include `#include<unistd.h>` in your code. However `#include<unistd.h>` and `mkfifo` only work in Unix environment. So execute the program in a Unix terminal. I had this problem and that's how I solved it.